# c# Linq request return nothing

Tags: c#, linq

I translated the following SQL query into a LINQ format but it does not return me anything.

```
SELECT DISTINCT BASEFILTER.EVPTCODE
FROM CONFIGURE, BASEFILTER, SITE
WHERE CONFIGURE.BASEFILTER_ID = BASEFILTER.ID
AND CONFIGURE.SITE_ID = SITE.ID;
```

Into :

```
var basefilterDB = (from conf in lConfigures
    join basef in lBasefilters on conf.BASEFILTER_ID equals basef.ID
    join site in lSites on conf.SITE_ID equals site.ID
    select new { basef.EVPTCODE }).Distinct();
```

When I run the SQL query in Oracle SQL Developer, it returns me results.

I do not get why it does not work in linq. It seems to be an easy request...

Many thanks !

Edit-------------

Answer :

```
var basefilterDB = (from conf in lConfigures
                 where conf.BASEFILTER_ID.Compare(conf.BASEFILTER_IDSource.ID)
                 select conf.BASEFILTER_IDSource.EVPTCODE).Distinct();
```

Compare(this byte[]) is a function to compare two byte[].

Comment: How are you attempting to then work on those results?

Comment: Try calling `ToList` after Distinct. It might not have been resolved by your succeeding calls.

Comment: @JonHanna 
`foreach (var item in basefilterDB)
                            {
                                testItemlList.ValueListItems.Add(new ValueListItem(item.EVPTCODE, item.EVPTCODE));
                            }`

basefilterDB is empty

Comment: @William I tried, but it still does not work :/

Comment: Are you sure your C# application and Oracle SQL Developer are connected to the same database? Does Oracle have any kind of tooling that lets you watch the statements as they execute (SQL Server has the Profiler tool that lets you do this) to ensure the SQL is correct?

Comment: @CraigW. Yes they are. I have a lot of other linq queries which work.
I do not know if there is such of tool, but when I look in debug mode I can see that lConfigures, lBasefilters and lSites are well filled from the DB with the corrects data.

Comment: Can you log the SQL sent by the app to the database? That might tell you enough to answer your question, and if not it might give you something you can add to here.

Comment: Given that I don't see a dbcontext referenced, what are `lConfigures`, `lBasefilters`, and `lSites`? Is this really a LINQ-to-Objects query?

Comment: I figured out. It did not work because it was comparing reference and not values in ID fields.
Thanks for your help, I post my answer as an edit in my post.

Comment: @Majestic Based on your edit, I think you can use `==` also if the id is primitive type

Comment: @SivaGopal This is what I tried first, but it was not working. Then I remind that I had a specific function to compare byte[].